# How to handle mysql inactivity error in thread

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I'm using MySQL in Django project, MYSQL and the server is running smoothly in normal site operation, but some operations are running in the thread. In thread after inactivity of 4-5hours it show error like:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (4031, 'The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior.')`
I tried different ways to reconnect and handle this error but not work, I'm using django ORM for db operations and db config is:

```
    db_config = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': DB_ENGINE,
            'NAME': DB_NAME,
            'USER': DB_USER,
            'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
            'HOST': DB_HOST,
            'PORT': DB_PORT,
            'CONN_MAX_AGE': 24*60*60,
            'POOL_OPTIONS': {
                'POOL_SIZE': 10,
                'MAX_OVERFLOW': 10,
                'RECYCLE': -1
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, db engin is `dj_db_conn_pool.backends.mysql`
used packages:

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.27
mysqlclient

apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: what's the environment in which you're running django? if its in development mode, then CONN_MAX_AGE will not work.

Comment: Yes I'm in development mode how can I solve this type of error in development?